# How do I read OS-compatible strings from stdin?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a Rust program that gets a separated list of filenames on `stdin`.

On Windows, I might invoke it from a `cmd` window with something like:

```
dir /b /s | findstr .*,v$ | rust-prog -n
```

On Unix I'd use something like:

```
find . -name '*,v' -print0 | rust-prog -0
```

I'm having trouble converting what I receive on `stdin` into something that can be used by `std::path::Path`. As I understand it, to get something that will compile on Windows or Unix, I'm going to need to use conditional compilation, and `std::os::windows::ffi` or `std::os::unix::ffi` as appropriate.

Furthermore, It seems on Windows I'll need to use `kernel32::MultiByteToWideChar` using the current code page to create something usable by `std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt`.

Is there an easier way to do this? Does what I'm suggesting even seem workable?

As an example, it's easy to convert a string to a path, so I tried to use the string handling functions of `stdin`:

```
use std::io::{self, Read};
fn main() {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(n) => println!("{}", buffer),
        Err(error) => println!("error: {}", error)
    }
}
```

On Windows, if I have a directory with a single file called `¿.txt` (that's 0xbf). and pipe the name into `stdin`. I get: `error: stream did not contain valid UTF-8`.

Comment: Can you explain what actual troubles you're seeing? Why do you think what you're receiving is not convertible to a `Path`? Have you observed errors of some sort.. ? Have you simply echoed the input to stdout and observed weird characters... ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I've added one example that gets errors.

Comment: Re-reading over your question, I realized that my answer was basically just reimplementing the logic that you already know you need to do; I wasn't offering anything *easier*. I can only point at resources like the [encoding crate](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-encoding) and [how to tell the code page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683162(v=vs.85).aspx). Sorry to provide false hope!

Comment: @Shepmaster: is this not a case where `OsString` would help? It seems to me that the first issue is assuming that the filenames will be valid Unicode (whatever their original encoding).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: `OsString` wouldn't help here. On Windows, an `OsString` is encoded in [WTF-8](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/) (this is an implementation detail), whereas the data received on stdin is encoded in the console's code page (which defaults to the OEM code page) by most of the built-in commands and OS-provided utilities on Windows.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Yes, of course encoding also needs be taken into account, my point was more that `String` is not suitable for the decoded product because Windows does not guarantee that a filename is Unicode (I think it accepts botched surrogate pairs for example).

Comment: That's right, Windows tolerates unpaired surrogates. That cannot happen with legacy code pages, but it can happen if the console's code page is set to UTF-16, so your concern is valid. If the standard library exposed APIs that directly accepted potentially ill-formed UTF-16 for OS strings on Windows, then the conversion from UTF-16 to `OsString` (which is not exposed in the library at the moment) would be unnecessary. It would be more efficient, too, since Rust has to convert an `OsString` to UTF-16 before calling any API that uses the string as an argument.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'd overlooked `OsString::from_wide()`. The code looks more reasonable now,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reasonable looking version for Windows. Convert the console supplied string to a wide string using win32api functions then wrap it in an OsString using `OsString::from_wide`.

I'm not convinced it uses the correct code page yet. `dir` seems to use OEM code page, so maybe that should be the default. There's also a distinction between input code page and output code page in a console.

In my `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
winapi = "0.2"
kernel32-sys = "0.2.2"
```

Code to read a list of filenames piped through stdin on Windows as per the question.

```
extern crate kernel32;
extern crate winapi;

use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::ptr;
use std::fs::metadata;
use std::ffi::OsString;
use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStringExt;

/// Convert windows console input to wide string that can
/// be used by OS functions
fn wide_from_console_string(bytes: &[u8]) -> Vec<u16> {
    assert!(bytes.len() < std::i32::MAX as usize);
    let mut wide;
    let mut len;
    unsafe {
        let cp = kernel32::GetConsoleCP();
        len = kernel32::MultiByteToWideChar(cp, 0, bytes.as_ptr() as *const i8, bytes.len() as i32, ptr::null_mut(), 0);
        wide = Vec::with_capacity(len as usize);
        len = kernel32::MultiByteToWideChar(cp, 0, bytes.as_ptr() as *const i8, bytes.len() as i32, wide.as_mut_ptr(), len);
        wide.set_len(len as usize);
    }
    wide
}

/// Extract paths from a list supplied as Cr LF
/// separated wide string
/// Would use a generic split on substring if it existed
fn paths_from_wide(wide: &[u16]) -> Vec<OsString> {
    let mut r = Vec::new();
    let mut start = 0;
    let mut i = start;
    let len = wide.len() - 1;
    while i < len {
        if wide[i] == 13 && wide[i + 1]  == 10 {
            if i > start {
                r.push(OsString::from_wide(&wide[start..i]));
            }
            start = i + 2;
            i = i + 2;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    if i > start {
        r.push(OsString::from_wide(&wide[start..i]));
    }
    r
}

fn main() {
    let mut bytes = Vec::new();
    if let Ok(_) = io::stdin().read_to_end(&mut bytes) {
        let pathlist = wide_from_console_string(&bytes[..]);
        let paths = paths_from_wide(&pathlist[..]);
        for path in paths {
            match metadata(&path) {
                Ok(stat) => println!("{:?} is_file: {}", &path, stat.is_file()),
                Err(e) => println!("Error: {:?} for {:?}", e, &path)
            }
        }
    }
}
```